# I want to change song name by using forEach method but it doesn't change and doesn't show any error

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach

I want to do basic operation like update with array of document. In this html I have song List (song-container) that contains song Item class. I want to change each song name and I tried below code but I did not received desire output.

```js
let songItem = Array.from(document.querySelector(".songItem"));
let songs = [
    {
        Name: "love  you zindagi",
        filePath: "audio/song1.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
    {
        Name: "zara-zara",
        filePath: "audio/song5.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
    {
        Name: "vaaste",
        filePath: "audio/song8.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
];

console.log(songs);

songItem.forEach((element, i) => {
    console.log(element, i);
    element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0].innerText = songs[i].Name;
});
```

```html
<div class="songList">
    <h1>Best Song Collection</h1>
    <div class="songItem">
        <span class="image">
            <img src="covers/download.jpg" />
        </span>
        <span class="songName">love you zindagi</span>
        <span class="timePlay"
            ><i class="far fa-play-circle" onclick="songPlay ()"></i
        ></span>
        <span class="timeStop"
            ><i class="far fa-pause-circle" onclick="pauseSong ()"></i
        ></span>
    </div>
    <div class="songItem">
        <span class="image">
            <img src="covers/download.jpg" />
        </span>
        <span class="songName">love you zindagi</span>
        <span class="timePlay"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="songItem">
        <span class="image">
            <img src="covers/download.jpg" />
        </span>
        <span class="songName">love you zindagi</span>
        <span class="timePlay"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may use [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355) next time. I already help you do it.

Comment: `element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0]` should probably be `element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answers, this line

```
let songItem = Array.from(document.querySelector(".songItem"));
```

returns only the first element with class name `"songItem"`. In order to return all of them you need to use `querySelectorAll`. Also, you don't have to use `Array.from()`. Therefore, you can use this line instead:

```
let songItem = document.querySelectorAll(".songItem");
```

On the other hand, in the last line, using `element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0]` might not be the best practice, since "element" has only one child element with class name "songName", you can use querySelector in this case; like this:

```
element.querySelector(".songName").innerText = songs[i].Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` returns the first element matching the selector. Use `querySelectorAll` instead to get an iterable of all matched elements.

```js
let songItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".songItem"));
let songs = [
    {
        Name: "love  you zindagi",
        filePath: "audio/song1.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
    {
        Name: "zara-zara",
        filePath: "audio/song5.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
    {
        Name: "vaaste",
        filePath: "audio/song8.mp3",
        coverPath: "covers/download.jpg",
    },
];

console.log(songs);

songItem.forEach((element, i) => {
    console.log(element, i);
    element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0].innerText = songs[i].Name;
});
```

Comment: Also, just remove `Array.from` because `NodeList` support `forEach`.